# Combobox SelectedItem is not retrieved properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radcombobox

I have saved all combobox values which are added dynmaically to a collection.
No i want to retrieve the info. When I retrieve it **my combobox values are not** displayed in it.

We use **Telerik** component here

```
<tele:RadComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DisplayMemberPath="content" ItemsSource="{Binding ManyValue,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyValue, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

ManyValue is a dropdown of values which has id,content
Myvalue is  selected value what I have selected in combobox

ManyValue is a collection of viewmodel to combobox.
MyValue is a property of ViewModel i.e. selected item of comboobox.

This is happening correctly when I select, But when I **retrieve** the data,In collection Items are present but **something wrong in Binding** so that am not able to display it.

I do the save properly. But when I retrieve unable to load the **already selected item in combobox.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: something wrong in <DisplayMemberPath="desc" ManyValue,Mode=TwoWay}"> ==> bad formated

Comment: @GCamel check it now

Comment: is "desc" a property of your dataitem ? and MyValue a property of your viewmodel ? (please reformat your question because not easy readable)

Comment: If `ManyValue` is name of a `DropDown`, you have to use `ElementName=ManyValue`, and `MyValue` should be a public property in `ViewModel`.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Both are public property, I do the save properly . But when I retrieve unable to load the selected item in combobox.

Comment: @SundarStalin Do the same code work with normal ComboBox.

Comment: Please post the class where the ManyValue and MyValue properties are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the SelectedItem,SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath did the trick for me